# Browser version detect using GWT?

Tags: browser, gwt, version-detection

Is there GWT api that will tell me which browser version it detected?

I've found a flaw with IE7's regex handling and need to code around some tricky  String.matches() expressions.

Comment: Could you describe the IE7 flaw for us? What is a sample regex and in what way IE7 gets it wrong (and other browsers get it right)? I don't think it affects the question or answers, just would be nice to have that information here for posterity.

Comment: I've got a password regex that matches==true in every browser tested besides IE7. 


PASSWORD_REGEX = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,24})"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use [GWT deferred binding using replacement](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html#replacement) and create two implementations of your class in which you use regex.

For example let's assume your class is named `Parser` and it contains code for all web browsers except for IE7. Then you can extend `Parser` and create `ParserIE7` class for IE7. Then in your GWT module config file you can add:

```
<replace-with class="Parser">
  <when-type-is class="Parser"/>
</replace-with>

<replace-with class="ParserIE7">
  <when-type-is class="Parser" />
  <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie7"/>
</replace-with>
```

Then by calling

```
Parser parser = GWT.create(Parser.class);
```

you should have a proper (web browser dependent) implementation of `Parser` in `parser` variable.

You can find more details [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html#replacement).

Comment: +1 This is a valid answer if you have a lot of changes between different parsers and want to minimize traffic between the server and the browser.

Answer (score 28):

You can detect the browser type using the code below.

```
public static native String getUserAgent() /*-{
return navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
}-*/;
```

Then you can call that function and look at the type of the browser. For example the code below decides whether it is internet explorer or not.

```
if(getUserAgent().contains("msie"))
{
///////// Write your code for ie
}
```

[This page](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/browser_ids.htm#msie) has the User Agent for just about every browser known to man.

Comment: How about [`Window.Navigator.getUserAgent()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Navigator.html#getUserAgent%28%29) instead of your JSNI method?

Comment: How would i know whether the browser is 'Mozilla Fire Fox/Safari/Opera/Chrome' or not. can you post the same condition for the other browsers as you have done for IE.

Comment: Also, this will return **false** for **IE11**, since it's userAgent string does not contain `msie`. One should use `contains("msie") || contains("trident")` to match **IE11**.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the GXT library, you can use **GXT**.isChrome to detect chrome and you can find **different data members of GXT class** to detect a particular browser.

Comment: Using 3rd party libraries for such basic/trivial tasks (regardless of popular they might be for other purposes) is very bad habit.

Comment: Downvoting is a bit harsh still though. And GXT is a very popular library, people finding this post may already be using it.